# Flash Builder code completion for flash libraries

Tags: flash, autocomplete, flash-builder

Is it possible to get auto completion for flash libraries in flash builder 4.0?

Comment: as long as you've got the .as files or the swc for those flash libraries linked to your project's library/classpath auto complete should work

Answer (score 0):

I'm using stand alone version of the Flash Builder for a couple of years and auto completion works fine. Anyway, sometimes Flash Builder could forget to help me, with  looking for errors or with auto completion, in this cases i select the .as file (with which i'm working right now), in the Project Explorer, and select *set it as default application*, this point Flash Builder that he should be something more than just text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to add the [Inspectable] metadata tag to the properties in your library that you want to expose.